# WebSocket in play 2.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.6

I was using `WebSocket` in play 2.2, now I want to migrate my application to play framework 2.6

Below is my code which I have written in play 2.2 framework

```
public static WebSocket<String> socketHandler() {
        return new WebSocket<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(In<String> in, Out<String> out) {
                try {
                    Socket.register(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), in, out);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to update it to play framework 2.6